# Adding new parameter to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure in my database that currently takes in and utilizes 11 parameters (all working great). I need to add a new parameter to this for a new column I added.

We always explicitly define our columns in code, so there was no issue adding a column to the end of the table. However, if I add a new parameter in my stored procedure to populate this new column, will it throw an error back to my C# code if it isn't supplied, or will it default to null (or some other value) for the parameter?

Example C# code to call the stored procedure:

```
public static void InsertMailLog(string messageId, DateTime sentOrReceivedDate,
        string fromAddress, string toAddress, string subject, string receivedMessage, string tailNumber,
        string messageType, string direction, string sentOrReceived, string distributionList, ILogger AppEventLog, string filename = null)
{
        List<string> lstParameterValues = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            lstParameterValues.Add(messageId ?? "");
            lstParameterValues.Add(sentOrReceivedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"));
            lstParameterValues.Add(fromAddress ?? "");
            lstParameterValues.Add(toAddress);
            lstParameterValues.Add(subject ?? "");
            lstParameterValues.Add(receivedMessage ?? "");
            lstParameterValues.Add(tailNumber ?? "");
            lstParameterValues.Add(messageType ?? "");
            lstParameterValues.Add(direction ?? "");
            lstParameterValues.Add(sentOrReceived ?? "");
            lstParameterValues.Add(distributionList ?? "");
            lstParameterValues.Add(filename ?? "");  //THIS IS NEW, but it has not been published yet as the SP hasn't been updated.

            CommonDAL.ExecSpNonQuery("spMailLogInsert", lstParameterValues);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CommonBLL.LogError(ex, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, "Error", messageId, tailNumber, messageType, "", Settings.Default.ContentProvider, AppEventLog);
        }
    }
```

Example stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMailLogInsert]
    @SdMessageId         varchar(50),
    @SentOrReceivedDate  datetime,
    @FromAddress         varchar(100),
    @ToAddress           varchar(100),
    @Subject             varchar(255),
    @Message             varchar(MAX),
    @TailNumber          varchar(50),   
    @MessageType         varchar(50),
    @Direction           varchar(50),
    @SentOrReceived      varchar(50),
    @DistributionList    varchar(50),
    @Filename            varchar(50)  --THIS IS NEW
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT MailLog (SdMessageId, SentOrReceivedDate, FromAddress, ToAddress,
                    [Subject], [Message], TailNumber, MessageType, Direction,
                    SentOrReceived, DistributionList, Filename  --THIS IS NEW
                   ) 
    VALUES (@SdMessageId, @SentOrReceivedDate, @FromAddress, @ToAddress,
            @Subject, @Message, @TailNumber, @MessageType,
            @Direction, @SentOrReceived, @DistributionList,
            @Filename  --THIS IS NEW
           )
```

I completely understand that this is a terrible use of a stored procedure. I should be using Entity Framework, but it's already written, and I have a project to update the entire project to use EF in the DAL at a later date (this is very old code).

My question is, if I add the new parameter `@Filename`" to the stored procedure *before* the new C# code above gets published, will I get an error, or will the stored procedure parameter simply default to NULL? Or, if someone has a better way to default this to NULL or empty string, if it isn't supplied, I'm all ears.

Comment: Why not try it and find out?

Comment: Because, if it will make it blow up, I'd rather not have production go down.  I don't have a test system to use.

Comment: @Vahlkron I'd say your *real* problem is not having a test system.  Even running SQL Server Express and IIS on your development machine is better than developing directly in production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could go ahead with the SP and just use a default parameter.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189330(v=SQL.105).aspx

```
@Filename            varchar(50) = NULL  --THIS IS NEW
```

Answer (score 9):

Either Make it nullable like this.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMailLogInsert]
    @SdMessageId         varchar(50),
    @SentOrReceivedDate  datetime,
    @FromAddress         varchar(100),
    @ToAddress           varchar(100),
    @Subject             varchar(255),
    @Message             varchar(MAX),
    @TailNumber          varchar(50),   
    @MessageType         varchar(50),
    @Direction           varchar(50),
    @SentOrReceived      varchar(50),
    @DistributionList    varchar(50),
    @Filename            varchar(50) = NULL --THIS IS NEW
......
```

Or Add a Default value like this:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMailLogInsert]
    @SdMessageId         varchar(50),
    @SentOrReceivedDate  datetime,
    @FromAddress         varchar(100),
    @ToAddress           varchar(100),
    @Subject             varchar(255),
    @Message             varchar(MAX),
    @TailNumber          varchar(50),   
    @MessageType         varchar(50),
    @Direction           varchar(50),
    @SentOrReceived      varchar(50),
    @DistributionList    varchar(50),
    @Filename            varchar(50) = 'abc.txt' --THIS IS NEW
......
```

Answer (score 3):

> I completely understand that this is a terrible use of a stored procedure.

Er, no? It's a simple sproc, sure, but if all your SQL are sprocs, then this is the way to go.

> I should be using Entity Framework [...]

Things in programming aren't always optimal, and you have to do what you have to do.

> [...] if I add the new parameter "Filename" to the stored procedure *before* the new C# code above gets published, will I get an error, or will the SP simply default to NULL?

SQL will throw an error that the new parameter wasn't supplied through it's caller (ASP.Net).  See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189330(v=SQL.105).aspx).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sales.uspGetSalesYTD
    @SalesPerson nvarchar(50) = NULL  -- NULL default value
AS
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on your Stored Procedure it is considered *required*.  To avoid it being required, you should add the following to your parameter:

```
@Filename varchar(50) = null
```

That will make it optional, which will allow you to avoid excessive Null checks in your code behind.  Which can make your code turn to spaghetti quickly.  This would be the easiest and least intrusive approach to solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a default value or it will get an error